# Date Format to a GridView populated with SQL in ASP.net - NOT boundfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, date-format

This is the code that creates the GridView everything else is happening with C#, I mean that is populated with the C# code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="STANDBY_JOURNALS Email.aspx.cs" Inherits="STANDBY_JOURNALS_Email.STANDBY_JOURNALS_Email" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SQL" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="SEND" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller">
        </asp:GridView>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to add Date format to this GridView, but if I try to use `BOUNDFIELD`, what it does, it creates a column at the beginning of the table, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Journal Date" DataFormatString="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

[image]

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace STANDBY_JOURNALS_Email
{
    public partial class STANDBY_JOURNALS_Email : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        SqlConnection vid = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxxxxx; Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxx;  User id=xxxxxx; Password=xxxxxxx");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sqlquery1 = "SELECT * FROM DBO.STANDBY_JOURNALS_DQMS WHERE [Ledger Grp] IN ('ACTUALS','GRP_FXRATE','CONSEGRP') AND [Source] = 'CON' OR [Source] LIKE 'Q%' ORDER BY [Source], [SystemDateTime],[SystemTime] ASC";

            String str = sqlquery1;
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);
            vid.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Name");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            vid.Close();
        }
        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
        }
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {


                    String EmailFrom = "xxxxxx@xxxxx.co.nz";
                    String EmailTo = "xxxxxx@xxxxx.co.nz";
                    String EmailSubject = "this is a subject";
                    //String EmailBody = "Cuerpo del Mensaje";



                    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
                    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(EmailFrom, EmailTo);
                    mm.Subject = EmailSubject;
                    mm.Body = "Report:<hr />" + sw.ToString(); ;
                    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.Port = 25;
                    smtp.Timeout = 20000;
                    smtp.Send(mm);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can help in how to affect the columns in the table created with the GridView?

Comment: Because you are using boundfield. edit format for your template field instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns` property of GridView to `false` (I think this is the only solution you looking for) and add BoundFields for all required columns.

Or if you are using TemplateFields then there are options to set date format for your `TemplateField`. No need to add `BoundField` like:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "date" 
      SortExpression="date" >
   <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblreceived_at" runat="server"
               Text='<%# Eval("date","{0:d}")%>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

For all options refer:
http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/137_How_to_format_DateTime_in_GridView_BoundColumn_and_TemplateColumn.aspx

Comment: Could you help me in how to include that to my code?.. because I have no idea

Comment: share your code for Journal Date field or full gridview code dont need c# code

Comment: if you are not using template fields only boundfields then you probably have two boundfields for Journal Date

Comment: I've added it to the top of the main post... That's all.. there is no more code, to populate the gridview I use just C#..Basically I've posted the whole code

Comment: but in output you are showing many columns. you only added line for gridview but i need grid view code with both Journal Date fields inside.

Comment: seriously, there is no more code.. I've just managed to make it work just like that

Comment: then you cant add boundfield it will be added to all others

Comment: then there are two ways either write boundfields for all fields or format date from code behind. try writing HeaderText="Journal Date" in boundfield

Comment: I've edited and posted the whole code..hopefully is easier to understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150134/discussion-between-diego-morales-sepulveda-and-preet).

Comment: @Diego Morales Sepulveda Glad to help1

Answer (score 2):

In BoudField, Try this format:

```
DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
```

Output:

```
01/06/2017 00:00:00
```

Comment: that does not work.. because I'm not using BOUNDFIELD

Comment: are you using mysql?

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following `Convert` function in your SQL query, your purpose will be achieved. For example:

```
Select CONVERT(varchar,YOUR_DATE_COLUMN,107) as JournalDate, * From YOUR_TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to just use SQL `MID()` in the query,

```
SELECT MID(Journal_Date,1,8) AS JD FROM DBO.STANDBY_JOURNALS_DQMS
```

It will give you

> 01/06/17

Comment: The data stored in the SQL table is DATE format.. it is converted to date time by the gridview.. so this solution won't work.. thanks mate